# Extract Matching Group Names: Cleaner way to do it?

Tags: c#, regex

Suppose I have a pattern in the form of `"((?<happy>foo)|(?<sad>bar)|...)"` .  There could be many more conditions.  If I wanted to know which grouping I had found (e.g. searching `12bar34` will return `"sad"`, is there a cleaner way to do it than the code I have now?

```
Regex objRegex = new Regex("((?<happy>foo)|(?<sad>bar))");
Match objMatch = objRegex.Match("12bar34");        
for (int i = 0; i < objMatch.Groups.Count; ++i)
{
    int tmp;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(objMatch.Groups[i].Value) &&
        !Int32.TryParse(objRegex.GroupNameFromNumber(i), out tmp))
    {
        //The name of the grouping.
        Trace.WriteLine(objRegex.GroupNameFromNumber(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(string groupName in objRegex.GetGroupNames())
{
   if (objMatch.Groups[groupName].Success)
      Trace.WriteLine(groupName);
}
```

Note though that that [`Regex.GetGroupNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.getgroupnames.aspx)also considers `"0"` to be a group (the entire match), so you may need to filter that out if you don't want it.

Comment: `Success` is what I was missing.

Comment: Haha, I was just editing my answer to get rid of the LINQ, which I thought wasn't really helping. Coincidence. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my answer since yours is close enough to my answer that posting my own version doesn't actually add anything.  I actually ended up just tracking which group number corresponded to which name.  In context, this way of doing it made things better.  `Success` was still very relevant, though.  I also got rid of the `tryParse` by not starting the `for` loop at 0.